# iOS  Solutions to display HTML contained in an NSString in a UIWebView

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to display an html present in my `NSString` into a `UIWebView`?

My solution is to write the html into a file and afterwards, parse it like this:

```
[WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

However, I would prefer a more elegant solution.

Comment: Could you give some details about why the solution you've already reached is not sufficient? This might keep anyone from suggesting a solution that would have the same drawbacks.

Comment: ditto - Thats as I would do it

Comment: 'cause I think that is not correct save the html into a file only to reuse to view it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use UIWebView loadHTMLString method.